# Import override in playwright component testing

Tags: reactjs, playwright, playwright-test

Is there a way to override import paths in [playwright component testing](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-components)?

Example -
In my react component file, I have these two imports -

```
import LocalizationWrapper from '.../Components/dojoWrappers/LocalizationWrapper';

import DojoWidgetHost from '.../Components/DojoWidgetHost';
```

In my playwright component test file, I want to override these two imports.

Is it possible?

Comment: Things usually are possible, but often not good ideas. [Why do you want to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676)? Usually, end to end tests don't need to mess with the code or mock much of anything. That's more of a unit test thing. If you're having to do this sort of surgery, you're probably making up for a bad design choice elsewhere that should be addressed.

Comment: There are components built using dojo and are used in our react components. They work fine in monolith. But when I am trying to run playwright component tests, they are erroring out on dojo syntaxes.

Comment: I don't know anything about Dojo, but isn't there a build stage that bundles everything down to vanilla JS? Playwright should be running on the live website that's the same as the user sees, so any imports should be resolved/handled the same way as the browser normally would based on your normal build output. In other words, whether the site is React, Dojo, Vue, Angular, jQuery, Schmojo, Playwright works exactly the same and doesn't care. It just opens the page and interacts with it based on locators. What am I missing?

Comment: Thats the case with Playwright test,  not playwright component test. In playwright component test, you can independently test react components. https://playwright.dev/docs/test-components

Comment: Ah, I had no idea about this feature. So I guess Playwright is offering unit tests now. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, if you have any recommendations or suggestions, please let me know